# Pass env var with line breaks from Python script to GitHub Actions

Tags: python, environment-variables, github-actions

I have a problem with writing multi-line comments on a GitHub PR based on a list of errors that I have in a Python script. Here are the details.

I have a Python script that is getting invoked by an invoke command in a GitHub Actions workflow:

```yaml
# ...

jobs:
  check-code:
    name: Run checks
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    ...

    steps:
       ...
         - name: Run python script
           run: inv return-errors.set-errors
       ...
```

The Python script is getting a list of errors and to share that list with the workflow outside I'm setting an environment variable. I'm doing so by adding it as a concatenated string with line breaks to the file where GitHub stores its environment variables.

```
import os

from invoke import task, Context


@task
def set_errors(ctx: Context):
    # example list of error messages
    my_errors_list = ["You have invalid email",
                      "You are too young",
                      "You are using the wrong provider for your rides"
                     ]

    # concatenate all error messages separated by line breaks
    my_errors_string = '\n'.join(my_errors_list)

    # get file for storing git environment variables
    file_path: str = os.environ.get('GITHUB_ENV', None)
    if file_path is None:
        raise OSError('Environment file not found')

    # add an entry for the error list
    with open(file_path, 'a') as gh_envs:
        gh_envs.write('ERROR_LIST=' + my_errors_string + '\n')
```

In the following step, I would then want to add the whole string as one comment to the PR by using the environment variable that is just set in the Python script:

```
      ...
      - name: Add comment
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          script: |
            github.rest.issues.createComment({
              issue_number: ${{ github.event.issue.number || github.event.number }},
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              body: ${{ env.ERROR_LIST }}
            })
```

I'm not reaching this point because it fails when running the Python script. It can't parse the second line of the environment variable definition in the file. The error is below.

```
Error: Unable to process file command 'env' successfully.
Error: Invalid format 'You are too young'
```

If I don't add line breaks in my environment variable, everything works and I can see the comment in the PR.

Do you know if there is a better way to achieve the goal of printing a multi-line comment to a PR when the data for the comment is available in a Python script? Or is my approach the only way to go and I just need to fix how I'm setting the environment variable?

Comment: Did you try setting it as a [multiline string](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions?tool=bash#multiline-strings)?

Comment: That multi-line string is for the GitHub actions. I can't use that in my Python script. 
However,  I played around with it and I could create a multi-line environment variable. This was just to test how it would work when setting the variable in a GitHub action. Unfortunately, it then did not work when passing that to the `createComment` command. I wonder how you can write a nicely formatted comment on your PR when this is so complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set that string as a [multiline env var](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions?tool=bash#multiline-strings).

Example:

```bash
ERRORS<<EOF
{errors}
EOF
```

You need to set it as a multiline string value in JavaScript as well with backticks against `body`.

Here's a complete working example:

```yaml
name: comment_on_issue

on: workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  ci:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Create comment
      shell: python
      run: |
        import os
        errors_list = [
          "You have invalid email",
          "You are too young",
          "You are using the wrong provider for your rides"
        ]
        errors_string = '\n'.join(errors_list)
        print(errors_string)
        file_path: str = os.environ.get('GITHUB_ENV', None)
        with open(file_path, 'a') as f:
            f.write('ERRORS<<EOF\n')
            f.write(errors_string + '\n')
            f.write('EOF\n')

    - name: Add comment
      uses: actions/github-script@v6
      with:
        github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        script: |
          github.rest.issues.createComment({
            issue_number: 36,
            owner: context.repo.owner,
            repo: context.repo.repo,
            body: `${{ env.ERRORS }}`
          })
```

Output:

[image: comment]